# Simple-dataTables with <Link>

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to get data into simple-dataTables that includes a link to a detail page. I can easily accomplish this using <a href but this is not ideal as it is causing a page refresh. How can I optimize the below code to use  without it outputting object Object? Thanks!

The Below Outputs object Object in the column where  is used

```
let tableData = [];

Object.entries(accountItems).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if(value.firstName) {
    tableData[key] = [value.firstName];
  }
  tableData[key].push(<Link to={`/management-edit/${value.id}`}>View Details</Link>);
});

let dataTable = new DataTable("#teamTable", {
  data: {
    headings:[
      "First Name",
      "Action"
    ],
    data: tableData
  },
});
```

This code works but refreshes the page when the link is clicked.

```
let tableData = [];

Object.entries(accountItems).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if(value.firstName) {
    tableData[key] = [value.firstName];
  }
  tableData[key].push(`<a href="/management-edit/${value.id}">View Details</a>`);
});

let dataTable = new DataTable("#teamTable", {
  data: {
    headings:[
      "First Name",
      "Action"
    ],
    data: tableData
  },
});
```

If anyone can help me figure out how to use the  tag to prevent the page refresh on clicking the link that would be awesome.

Comment: So you swapped raw anchor tags for a `Link` component. What is the issue or problem? Are the `Link` components not working as expected?

Comment: Yeah the <Link> component is outputting object Object instead of a link like it usually does.

Comment: Oh, I see, looks like you need to pass an HTML string. What is `DataTable`? You probably need to check that object's library's documentation for how to pass JSX if that's even possible. Can you [edit] to provide a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: This short blog post might be helpful/informative: https://www.emmanuelgautier.com/blog/react-element-render-to-string Basic gist is to render the React JSX and stringify it so you can pass the HTML string. Something like ```const htmlString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Link to={`/management-edit/${value.id}`}>View Details</Link>);```.